# Listing employees, categorized by license expiration date

Tags: performance, ruby, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pagination

I am working on a personal project and I have hit a wall. I know I am writing bad code and I really want to refactor the code below. The application has three tables on the same page. Each table contains data from a has-many-though relationship. In essence I have an employees page which contains three tables of employee licenses that all expire in grouped intervals:

ALL EMPLOYEE PAGE

- Employees with licenses Expiring in 30 days
- Employees with licenses Expiring in 30-90 days
- Employees with licenses Expiring in 90 days

All three of these tables are independently paginated and I am allowing the user to enter a search term and search across all three tables.

However I have over 1200 licenses so the page is taking forever to load. How can I optimize this functionality? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Model

```
  def self.emp_lic_small
   self.all.map{|se| se.employee_licenses.less_than_thirty}.flatten
  end

  def self.emp_lic_medium
    self.all.map{|se| se.employee_licenses.between_thirty_and_ninty}.flatten
  end

  def self.emp_lic_large
    self.all.map{|se| se.employee_licenses.greater_than_ninty}.flatten
  end
```

### Controller

```
    @small_employee_licenses = SiteEmployee.search(params[:search]).emp_lic_small.paginate(:page => params[:small_lic], :per_page => 20)
    @medium_employee_licenses = SiteEmployee.search(params[:search]).emp_lic_medium.paginate(:page => params[:med_lic], :per_page => 20)
    @large_employee_licenses = SiteEmployee.search(params[:search]).emp_lic_large.paginate(:page => params[:large_lic], :per_page => 20)
```

### View

```
<div class="panel panel-danger">
  <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Employee Licenses Expiring in Less Than 30 Days</strong></div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <th class="text-center">Employee Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Employed By</th>
            <th class="text-center">License Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Expiration Date</th>
            <th class="text-center">Obtained?</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% if @small_employee_licenses.present? %>
                <% @small_employee_licenses.each do |e| %>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= link_to e.site_employee.to_s, site_employee_path(e.site_employee)%></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= link_to e.site_employee.site.name, site_path(e.site_employee.site)%></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= e.license.name %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= e.expiration_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= e.obtained? ? "Yes" : "No" %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <%end%>
            <% else %>
                <tr><td colspan="3">There are currently no Licenses due in the next 30 days.</td></tr>
            <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<%= will_paginate @small_employee_licenses, param_name:'small_lic' unless @small_employee_licenses.blank?  %> 

<div class="panel panel-warning">
  <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Employee Licenses Expiring in 30-90 Days</strong></div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <th class="text-center">Employee Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Employed By</th>
            <th class="text-center">License Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Expiration Date</th>
            <th class="text-center">Obtained?</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% if @medium_employee_licenses.present? %>
                <% @medium_employee_licenses.each do |e| %>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= link_to e.site_employee.to_s, site_employee_path(e.site_employee)%></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= link_to e.site_employee.site.name, site_path(e.site_employee.site)%></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= e.license.name %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= e.expiration_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= e.obtained? ? "Yes" : "No" %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <%end%>
            <% else %>
                <tr><td colspan="3">There are currently no Licenses due in the next 30 days.</td></tr>
            <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<%= will_paginate @medium_employee_licenses, param_name:'med_lic' unless @medium_employee_licenses.blank?  %> 
<div class="panel panel-success">
  <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Employee Licenses Expiring in 30-90 Days</strong></div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <th class="text-center">Employee Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Employed By</th>
            <th class="text-center">License Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Expiration Date</th>
            <th class="text-center">Obtained?</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% if @large_employee_licenses.present? %>
                <% @large_employee_licenses.each do |e| %>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= link_to e.site_employee.to_s, site_employee_path(e.site_employee)%></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= link_to e.site_employee.site.name, site_path(e.site_employee.site)%></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= e.license.name %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= e.expiration_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= e.obtained? ? "Yes" : "No" %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <%end%>
            <% else %>
                <tr><td colspan="3">There are currently no Licenses due in the next 30 days.</td></tr>
            <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<%= will_paginate @large_employee_licenses, param_name:'large_lic' unless @large_employee_licenses.blank?  %>
```

Comment: I'd wager the bottleneck is in the model methods. You're mapping `all` records. I can't tell from the code exactly _what_ you're scoping that to  – what model is this from? And what's `se`? Are the lists scoped to something before searching? – but you're looking for licenses, but seem to be going the long way of finding licenses _through_ something. It also implies that the pagination happens late - after a lot of stuff has been loaded. So the pagination is the act of throwing a lot of it away, rather than loading what you need. But your question doesn't have enough detail, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Could you post how these tables are related? (the `has_many`, etc, for the tables in the example?)

Comment: Do you really need all 1200 employees to be displayed before asking the user to search for one? Why not first ask for a search term and then to accordingly display results?

Comment: @Flambino i think 'se' stands for SiteEmployee

Answer (score 1):

You should probably reduce the number of database queries, first you repeat the SiteEmployee search 3 times. Do it once and store it in a a variable. I would also query the database once with an `order` clause together with the `Enumerable` `group_by` method to get all of the results in one go.